# Having an issue applying a function to a dataset

Tags: r, function

I'm struggling with this written function, which doesnt apply to my dataset

```
narandom <- function(x, y) {
  x[is.na(
    x
  )] <-
    sample(y, sum(
      is.na(
        x
      )
    ), replace = TRUE)
}

tabellaeco[, 72] <- narandom(tabellaeco$`Saresti disposto a pagare in più per avere accesso a cibi e bevande biologici e di alta qualità presso la mensa universitaria e/o presso i distributori automatici?`, 1:3)
```

Running the code gives me this error

```
Error in `[<-`:
! Assigned data `narandom(...)` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 258 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 44 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 44 to size 258.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Thing is, the function only returns a vector with the randomized NAs, excluding the existing values, so I cant manage to properly apply it to my dataset.

So far I only tried this manually without using a written function, and it works

Comment: I didn't look at this too much (on a train), but I think what happens is that you define a column as x, and should then create a loop for it to handle the 'i' element each time. In the meantime, upload a reproducible code that we can copy and try ourselves, including your data (or a sample of it using dput)

Comment: can you try adding ```return(x)``` at the end of the function?

Comment: @peter861222's comment is likely the culprit, unable to test due to lack of sample data and I don't know where `narandom` is defined. The "return value" from a function, if `return(.)` is not used explicitly, is the last expression evaluated. In this case, it's `x[..] <- sample(..)`; the value returned (invisibly) by `<-` is the value assigned, in this case it's the likely-different-sized `sample(.)`, not the _whole_ value of `x`. The literal use of `return(.)` is not required (it hads micro-overhead), just adding `x` as the last expression in the function is likely to work.

Comment: Using return(x) correctly returns me all the observations.

Comment: As a demonstration, start with `vec <- 1:10`, then see that `(vec[2:3] <- c(99,98))` (the surrounding parens make the invisible return-value _visible_ and does nothing else to the expression) returns just `c(99, 98)` instead of the whole updated value of `vec`.

Comment: Managed to make it work! I only had to add an x before closing the brackets. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is fine. Just add the return statement.

```
arandom <- function(x, y) {
  x[is.na(x)] <-sample(y, sum(is.na(x)), replace = TRUE)
return(x)
}
set.seed(2)
tabellaeco <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(NA,1:5),10,TRUE),
  new_x = NA
  
)
tabellaeco$new_x <- arandom(tabellaeco$x,1:3)
tabellaeco
    x    new_x
1   4     4
2   5     5
3   5     5
4  NA     3
5   4     4
6  NA     1
7   3     3
8   4     4
9  NA     3
10  1     1
```

Be aware that in order for the changes to apply you need to assign the function to a variable (otherwise it will print, but not update)